# Php export table to excel

Tags: php, excel, export

I have this code that exports a html table to excel.

```
print $obj->methodThatReturnTable();

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

It works fine for tables with a few rows, but now I have created a table with almost 1000 rows (8 columns) and instead of the download be forced, the table is showed in the browser.

What could be happening?

Comment: You must send headers before print your excel content with $obj->methodThatReturnTable()

Comment: I did that and the download was the php file

Comment: Your "Content-Type" header is duplicated, is that normal ?


Try : 

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$obj->methodThatReturnTable();

Can you post the content of your methodThatReturnTable function ?

Comment: I guess it's normal, because it works for table with a few rows. The content of the method just return a table in html. It's too many lines to be posted, won't help. I THINK the problem is the size of the table, but I can't find anything to solve this problem...

Comment: The html content should net be converted to an excel content.
You must use a library like https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: The excel content it's not an html stream.
Your HTML content will not be a real xls content.

Comment: Ok, but I can't change all the source right now...

Comment: I know, but it's not the right way to do this.
It's better to start things properly.
The lib i recommanded you will facilate your job when you should use xls specific features like "Formula"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63500/discussion-between-anas-and-gbvisconti).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [PHP: Exporting Data to Excel](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/). It may help you.